# Переместить консольное окно другого процесса

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Есть код:

```
var p = Process.Start(@"...firstProc.exe");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
Process.Start(@"...secondProc.exe");
```

Можно ли как то программно указать позицию для консольных окон?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(@""))
        {
            var p1 = Process.Start(@".exe");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            var p2 = Process.Start(@".exe");

            MoveWindow(p1.MainWindowHandle, 1000, 200, 500, 200, true);
        }
    }
```